# Sklearn's LogisticRegression C hyperparameter issue

Tags: logistic, python, scikit-learn, regularization

In [sklearn user's guide for LogisticRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression) it is said that:

[image]

where C is

[image]

so, shouldn't C hyperparameter be in front of the regularization term r(w) rather than in front of the sum?

Answer (score 3):

There are two components in the mentioned cost function: error and regularization.

When you want to change the weight of one of the components by C times you can do one of the following:

- multiply that component by C
- divide **another** component by C

So minimizing $ C \times error + regularization$ is equivalent to minimizing $error + \frac{1}{C} \times regularization$

Second formula allows to understand what "Inverse of regularization strength" means, and why "smaller values of C specify stronger regularization", but both formulas are equivalent.