# Explicit form of L2 regularization in sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV

Tags: regression, logistic, python, scikit-learn, ridge-regression

I am using LogisticRegressionCV of sklearn, and I would like to know the explicit form of the L2 regularization in Logistic Regression.
In the [official page of LogisticRegressionCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV.html), it is written $Cs$ is "inverse of regularization strength", but it is not clear what is the explicit form of the regularization term.

In the [lecture note of Ridge regression](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.09169.pdf), the first equation in 5.3, it is written the regularization term of Ridge regression is $-\frac{1}{2}\lambda \bf{\beta}^T \bf{\beta}$, but I am not sure how this $\lambda$ is related to the $Cs$ above. Could anyone help me on this question?
(I also posted the same question in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78147133/explicit-form-of-l2-regularization-in-sklearn-linear-model-logisticregressioncv))

Additional Clarification: I was noted that this question is similar to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/637416/sklearns-logisticregression-c-hyperparameter-issue), but I am not sure what is the explicit relationship between $Cs$ and $\lambda$. Is $Cs=\frac{1}{\lambda}$, $Cs=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}\lambda}$, or else?

Comment: Suppose your regularized loss function is $$ L +\frac{ \lambda}{2} \| \beta \|_2^2.$$ Then if you multiply it by $C=\frac{1}{\lambda}$ you have $$CL +\frac{1}{2} \| \beta \|_2^2.$$ If you have a different loss function in mind, then the relationship can be different, but this is the relationship that holds for this particular sklearn model.

Comment: I don't understand the discussion above, are you claiming it does not matter how to define the constant part of $\bf{\beta}^T \bf{\beta}$ term?
It looks to me it does matter, because I want to know specifically the relationship between parameter $Cs$ of sklearn and $\lambda$ term in the regularization term.

Comment: As with every other ridge regression model, the intercept aka constant aka bias is omitted from regularization; this is explained in a duplicate. `LogisticRegressionCV` is a wrapper that does [tag:cross-validation]; it fits some number of logistic regressions, each using a $C$ from the **sequence** of $C$s values. My comment and a duplicate gives you the exact, specific relationship between $C$ and $\lambda.$ If you have further questions, you'll need to [edit] to be specific about what you know, what you'd like to know, and where you are stuck.